# How to checked checkbox using state in react in class based components

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project I am trying to checked checkbox using state in react, but Unable to do it After I checked checkbox using state. I need to change state using setState.
For example If I have checked using state then when I click the checkbox, then it has to change its state to checked: false.

If I am not clear put a comment.

This is code

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      checked: true
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input  style ={{defaultChecked: this.state.checked}} type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `checked` attribute of `<input>` rather than `style`?

Comment: Hi @YevgenGorbunkov If I put checked attribute it will work fine but I am trying to this with state and setState.

Comment: Use `onChange()` event handler to do `setState()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      checked: true
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input onClick={()=>this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked})} checked={this.state.checked} style ={{defaultChecked: this.state.checked}} type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Cruse, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input checked={this.state.checked} type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

You can then add onClick() or onChange() to handle the setState.